# Whats wrong with my if else code?

Tags: python

Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong with my code?
I'm using Python 3.6. And a beginner. Thanks!

```
import random

dice1 = random.randint(1, 2)
user_input = input("Guess a number: ")

if dice1 == user_input:
    print("Well Done!")
else:
    print("Try again")
```

Comment: A number is never going to equal a string.

Comment: @Li357 in this case when entered a number `user_input` will be int though

Comment: No it is a string until it is explictly converted (in python 3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: @user1767754 In Python 3, `input` returns a string, no?

Comment: `Python2` it returns int and `Python3` string. :D We were both right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input()` returns a [string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#textseq), so you have a string in `user_input`. In `dice1`, you have an [integer](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric). Try `print(type(user_input))` and `print(type(dice1))`. You cannot compare values of different types.

Convert the value in `user_input` to an `int`, then compare it with `dice1`, like so:

```
import random

dice1 = random.randint(1, 2)
user_input = input("Guess a number: ")
user_input = int(user_input)
# You could replace the above two user_input statements with:
# user_input = int(input("Guess a number: ")) # Uncomment before using

if dice1 == user_input:
    print("Well Done!")
else:
    print("Try again")
```

Running the above code:

```
Guess a number: 1
Well Done!
>>>
```

More about [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> **input**([prompt])
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Comment: Thank you very much srig. That corrected my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really looking for is a `while loop` that keeps asking for the `hidden` number as long as you have the wrong answer. As the user Li357 stated, in `Python3` the input is always a string, so you have to convert it to an int. In `Python2` you wouldn't have to put the `int` (just in this specific case)

```
import random

dice1 = random.randint(1, 2)
user_input = None


while(dice1 != user_input):                          #Keep asking
    user_input = int(input("Guess a number: "))      #Input to int
    if int(user_input) == dice1:                     #Now you check int vs int
        print("Well Done!")
        break                                        #If found, break from loop
    else:
        print("Try Again!")
```

Answer (score -1):

convert the input to an integer:

```
import random

dice1 = random.randint(1, 2)
user_input = int(input("Guess a number: "))

if dice1 == user_input:
    print("Well Done!")
else:
    print("Try again")
```

Comment: please explain the rationale for the down vote. This works as the op intended. The op is using python 3.6